# Spring Boot JPA Schema Initialization

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I want to initialise my datasource with a DLL script in my spring boot project (only during dev of course). As mentioned in the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) I set the `spring.datasource.schema` property to the DLL scripts which is in `src/main/resources/postgresql/define-schema.sql`.

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    platform: postgresql
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: ****
    initialize: true
    schema: ./postgresql/define-schema.sql
    continue-on-error: false
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      generate-ddl: false
      show-sql: true
```

But the script won't be executed. I also tried to put it on the class path root and call it schema.sql ... Nothing happens.

The `dev` profile is selected, at least I see it in the log: `The following profiles are active: dev`
The application than fails on the JPA schema validation.

The only warning I get from hibernate:
`Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.`
But I don't think this has any to do with the initialise problem.

I've got spring-boot-security-starter in my dependencies but not configured yet, could that be a problem source?

Does anybody recognise an obivous typo, mistake anything else?

Looking forward hearing from you!

Amp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix the path to your sql script with `classpath`

Example:

```
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/postgresql/define-schema.sql
```